# занятые плиз рассставьте кто раставит добро)

Tags: пунктуация

На террасе обращённая к саду сидели в креслах брат и сестра . Из сада на болкон вбежал Сергей прагывший через три ступеньки и остановился у перил

Comment: Похоже на розыгрыш доверчивых людей: сам текст и ошибки в нем вызывают сомнение своей неестественностью. Думаю, что не стоит работать с таким материалом, результат в любом случае не будет иметь пользы и не доставляет эстетического удовольствия.

Comment: Вера, насчет ошибок ничего сказать не могу, но, кажется, что очередное д/з.

Comment: А по-моему, Вера права: игра слов *запятые-занятые*, *прагывший* вместо *прыгавший* вызывают подозрения.

Answer (score 4):

Запятых-то не жалко, а с орфографией что? Оставим как есть?

На террасе, обращённ**ОЙ** к саду, сидели в креслах брат и сестра. Из сада на б**А**лкон вбежал Сергей, пр**Ы**г**А**вший через три ступеньки, и остановился у перил.

Вам русский язык неродной? Тогда это надо оговаривать в пояснении к вопросу...

Это самый простой случай обособления причастных оборотов, стоящих после определяемого слова.

А вот как выглядело бы наоборот:

*На обращённой к саду террасе сидели в креслах брат и сестра. Из сада на балкон вбежал прыгавший через три ступеньки Сергей и остановился у перил.*

Оно, конечно, косноязычненько, но и оригинал не страдал строгим и стройным слогом.